# Understanding the running time analysis from an exercise of CLRS

Tags: algorithm, asymptotic-complexity, clrs

Here's the problem I am looking for an answer for:

An array A[1...n] contains all the integers from 0 to n except one. It would be easy to determine the missing
integer in O(n) time by using an auxiliary array B[0...n] to record which numbers appear in A. In this
problem, however, we cannot access an entire integer in A with a single operation. The elements of A are
represented in binary, and the only operation we can use to access them is ”fetch the jth bit of A[i],” which
takes constant time.
Show that if we use only this operation, we can still determine the missing integer in O(n) time.

I have this approach in mind:
If I didn't have the above fetching restriction, I would have taken all the numbers and did an XOR of them together. Then XOR the result with all numbers from 1..n. And the result of this would be my answer. 
In this problem similarly I can repeatedly XOR the bits of different numbers at a distance of log(n+1) bits with each other for all elements in array and then XOR them with the elements 1...n  but the complexity comes out to be O(nlogn) in my opinion.

How to achieve the O(n) complexity?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a variation of [radix sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort):

sort numbers according to MSb (Most Significant bit)

You get two lists of sizes n/2, n/2-1. You can 'drop' the list with n/2 elements - the missing number is not there.

Repeat for the second MSb and so on.

At the end, the 'path' you have chosen (the bit with the smaller list for each bit) will represent the missing number.

Complexity is `O(n + n/2 + ... + 2 + 1)`, and since `n + n/2 + .. + 1 < 2n` - this is `O(n)`

---

This answer assumes for simplicity that `n=2^k` for some integer `k` (this relaxation can be later dropped off, by doing s 'special' handle for the MSb).

Answer (score 0):

You have n integers with range [0..n]. You can inspect every number's most significant bit and divide these number into to groups C(with MSB 0) and D(with MSB 1). Since you know the range is [0..n], you can calculate how many numbers with MSB 0 in this range, called S1, and how many number with MSB 1 in this range, called S2. If the size of C is not equal to S1, then you know the missing number has MSB 0. Otherwise, you know the missing number has MSB 1. Then, you can recursively solve this problem. Since each recursive call takes linear time and each recursive call except the first one can half the problem size, the total running time is linear.